# Stop fadeToggle() from building up

Tags: jquery

When I hover over what I want fading in and out too many times, then it keeps repeating itself. Even when I stop hovering it. How can I stop this?

```
$(".featured").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("h3").fadeToggle(800);
   });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `.stop()`

```
$(this).find("h3").stop(true, true).fadeToggle(800);
```

Parameters indicate: clearQueue, jumpToEnd
This will almost immediately stop the current animation. To have a more smooth stopping, you should call `.stop(true, false)`

Another way I can think of is to check whether the element is animated or not:

```
$(".featured").hover(function(){
    var $h3 = $(this).find('h3');

    if(!$h3.is(':animated') ) 
        $h3.fadeToggle(800);
});
```

Reference: [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), [:animated selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Comment: One question, what does the ! symbol mean? Thanks

Comment: @Trippy: it's the logical `NOT`. So, the `.fadeToggle()` is only applied if the element is NOT currently animated.